# Retrieving password for non working email address that is attached to an iCloud account

Tags: icloud

I have an iCloud account out that there that is attached to an email address that is no longer working. So I cannot do a password reset, because that email address is not working. So I cannot re-set it.

I need to get the pictures downloaded from that old iCloud account and add them to my new iCloud account. But I can't log in to get that done.

Hoping someone can help.

Comment: seriously!  how did that happen? did you check your keychain for the iCloud password!

Answer (score 1):

While I can assume that you ask due to having forgotten the password, it is not clear from your question.

In case you still know the password, you can log on to the iCloud account at [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com), change the e-mail address and make it the primary e-mail address.

NOTE: Obviously, you cannot use an e-mail address you already associated with an Apple ID in a different account.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to re-create the same email and use it to recover the iCloud password on your account.

Comment: Generally speaking, if the user states the email address is no longer working, creating it again is not an option either. It may be with a former employer, or a domain they no longer control, or any of myriad reasons.